# Google Maps HeatmapLayer background

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created some heatmapLayers and I've noticed that as I add and remove them they affect the background color of the entire map component, even the areas that have utterly no data points even close.  The amount the map background changes depends on the alpha value below in the rgba values.

Is there a way to add heatmap layers without affecting the areas of the map that don't have any data points?

```
 heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      map: map, data: data, radius: radius,  dissipating: dissipating,   opacity: opacity, maxIntensity: intensity,
      gradient: [
                    'rgba(255,    255,  0, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255,    255,  0, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(255,    255,  0, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,    255,  0, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(255,    255,  0, 1.0)']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my first gradient set to 0.2 instead of 0.0, so it was using 0.2 alpha for empty space.